# Ionic : How to set selected item in center by default in ion-scroll view

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-scroll

Calender view is set in scrollview but today selected date is not automatically set in center of the view.

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100vw; height:80px;overflow: hidden;" >
      <ion-row nowrap class="headerChip">
        <div *ngFor="let j of days">
          <button ion-button [ngClass]="{'':(j.isSelected==false),'todayBg':(j.isToday==true) ,'selectedBg':(j.isSelected==true)}" (click)="clickDate(j)">{{j.day}}<br>{{j.displayDate}}</button>
        </div>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: Any one have idea? I am newbie in ionic.